# Why is edit a specific Product is being displayed as a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I'm creating an admin panel where an admin is able to add a product to their website and then the product is then pushed to `firestore` database and also in `redux-toolkit` from `firestore`. I am displaying the added products in my `viewProduct`, in `viewProducts` an admin can edit or delete a product, so whenever I (*admin*) click on the edit button it takes me to that path but displays a blank page with no errors in console

Here is the `AddProduct.jsx` file where I'm adding or editing a product depending upon the id

AddProduct.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BsArrowDownCircle } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Loader from "../loader/Loader";
import { selectProducts } from "../../redux/slice/productSlice";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import {
  deleteObject,
  getDownloadURL,
  getStorage,
  ref,
  uploadBytesResumable
} from "firebase/storage";
import { db, storage } from "../../pages/firebase/config";
import { Timestamp, addDoc, collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

//import { addProduct } from "../../redux/actions";

// we were to enable storage tab by gpt's method and fix the add product to firebase storage
const categories = [
  { id: 1, name: "Laptop" },
  { id: 2, name: "Electronics" },
  { id: 3, name: "Fashion" },
  { id: 4, name: "Phone" }
];

const initialState = {
  name: "",
  imageURL: "",
  price: 0,
  category: "",
  brand: "",
  desc: ""
};

const AddProduct = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  //const numericId = parseInt(id)
  const products = useSelector(selectProducts);

  const productEdit = products.find((item) => item.id === id);
  console.log(productEdit)
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(() => {
    const newState = detectForm(id, { ...initialState }, productEdit);
    return newState;
  });
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  //upload progress is useless for now
  const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState(0);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function detectForm(id, f1, f2) {
    if (id === "ADD") {
      return f1;
      console.log("Add");
    }
    return f2;
    console.log("edit");
  }

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setProduct({ ...product, [name]: value });
    console.log("Updated Product: ", { ...product, [name]: value });
  };
 

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `eshop/${Date.now()}${file.name}`);
    console.log(storageRef);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
    console.log(uploadTask);
    // creating  reference to the storage location where the product image will be saved using the ref() method of the storage object.
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        setUploadProgress(progress); // upload progress aka useless
      },
      (error) => {
        toast.error(error.message);
      },
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          setProduct({ ...product, imageURL: downloadURL });
          console.log(product);
          //toast.success("Image uploaded successfully.");
        });
      }
    );
  };

  // add product
  const addProduct = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(product);
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      // maybe here
      const docRef = addDoc(collection(db, "products"), {
        name: product.name,
        imageURL: product.imageURL,
        price: Number(product.price),
        category: product.category,
        brand: product.brand,
        desc: product.desc,
        createdAt: Timestamp.now().toDate()
      });
      setIsLoading(false);
      setUploadProgress(0);
      setProduct({ ...initialState });

      toast.success("Product uploaded successfully.");

      navigate("/admin/all-products");
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      toast.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const editProduct = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);

    if (product.imageURL !== productEdit.imageURL) {
      const storageRef = ref(storage, productEdit.imageURL);
      deleteObject(storageRef);
    }
    try {
      setDoc(doc(db, "products", id), {
        name: product.name,
        imageURL: product.imageURL,
        price: Number(product.price),
        category: product.category,
        brand: product.brand,
        desc: product.desc,
        createdAt: productEdit.createdAt,
        editedAt: Timestamp.now().toDate()
      });
      setIsLoading(false);
      toast.success("Product Edited Successfully");
      navigate("/admin/all-products");
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      toast.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading && <Loader />}
      <div>
        <div className="container mt-5 mr-4">
          <h2>{detectForm(id, "Add New Product", "Edit Product")}</h2>
          <form onSubmit={detectForm(id, addProduct, editProduct)}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="productName" className="add-product-text">
                Product Name
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="productName"
                name="name"
                value={product.name}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                placeholder="Enter Product Name"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="productImage" className="add-product-text">
                Product Image
              </label>
              <br />
              <div className="custom-file">
                <input
                  type="file"
                  className="custom-file-input"
                  id="productImage"
                  placeholder="Product Image"
                  name="imageURL"
                  onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="productPrice" className="add-product-text">
                Product Price
              </label>
              <input
                type="number"
                className="form-control"
                id="productPrice"
                placeholder="Enter Product Price"
                name="price"
                value={product.price}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="productCategory" className="add-product-text">
                Product Category
              </label>
              <div className="select-box">
                <select
                  className="form-control"
                  id="productCategory"
                  name="category"
                  value={product.category}
                  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                  required
                >
                  <option>-- Choose Product Category --</option>
                  {categories.map((category) => {
                    return (
                      <option key={category.id} value={category.name}>
                        {category.name}
                      </option>
                    );
                  })}
                </select>
                <i
                  className="fas fa-chevron-down"
                  onClick={() => {
                    const select = document.getElementById("productCategory");
                    select.size = select.options.length;
                    select.focus();
                  }}
                >
                  <BsArrowDownCircle />
                </i>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="productBrand" className="add-product-text">
                Product Company/Brand
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="productBrand"
                placeholder="Enter Product Company/Brand"
                name="brand"
                value={product.brand}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="productDescription" className="add-product-text">
                Product Description
              </label>
              <textarea
                className="form-control"
                id="productDescription"
                rows="5"
                value={product.desc}
                name="desc"
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
                required
              ></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-5">
              {detectForm(id, "Save Product", "Edit Product")}
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddProduct;
```

It is correctly routing and detecting the `addProduct` and I am able to add product to my application but whenever I  click on the edit Product it gives a blank page

viewPRoduct.js file

```
<Link to={`/admin/add_product/${id}`}>
  <FaEdit size={20} color="green" />
</Link>
```

Here is the logic for routing

App.jsx

```
<Route
  path="/admin/*"
  element={
    <div>
      {userEmail === "huzasinn@gmail.com" ? <Admin /> : <Home />}
    </div>
  }
/>
```

admin.jsx

```
<div className="admin">
  <div className="admin-navbar-container">
    <AdminNavbar />
  </div>
  <div className="admin-content-container ">
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to= "/admin/home" />} />
      <Route path="/home" element={<AdminHome />} />
      <Route path="/all-products" element={<ViewProducts />} />
      <Route path="/add-product/:id" element={<AddProduct />} />
      <Route path="/orders" element={<Orders />} />
      <Route path="/order-details/:id" element={<OrderDetails />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</div>
```

adminNavbar.jsx

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <NavLink className={activeLink} activeClassName="active" to="/admin/home">
      Home
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink className={activeLink} activeClassName="active" to="/admin/all-products">
      View Products
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink className={activeLink} activeClassName="active" to="/admin/add-product/ADD">
      Add Product
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink className={activeLink} activeClassName="active" to="/admin/orders">
      Orders
    </NavLink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems from the route that you are expecting the `id` route path param from `"/admin/add-product/:id"` to be either `"ADD"` and (*probably*) `"EDIT"` (*although if it's anything other than `"ADD"` it's in "edit mode"*). There is then a search in a `products` array where the `id` path param is compared to `item.id` values. Do the product items *really* have `id` properties that are either `"ADD"` or `"EDIT"`, or am I misunderstanding the code somewhere? Is it the ```<Link to={`/admin/add_product/${id}`}>``` that gets the UI in "edit mode"? Can you share what `products` array value is?

Comment: @Drew Reese yes every product that is passed to firestore db has an id, like when i am displaying the products in viewProduct.jsx(which is an admin file to dsiplay all the products in the store from where an admin can delete/edit products) i am fetching the products from db as

  (snapshot) => {
            const productsData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data()
            }));
 // remaining code

Comment: Looks like you may've linked to a draft sandbox. When I try to access it there is an error message saying "something when wrong".

Comment: yeah sorry i checked there are few issues and also i have to change a bit of logic so that even a non admin user can access admin panel, i'll provide a correct and workign link in no time inshAllah @Drew Reese

Comment: The sandbox link still seems to say "something went wrong" when I try to access it.

Comment: hmm okay let me see what i can do @Drew Reese

Comment: hey @Drew Reese the link is too big which will send u to the app, so i'm gonna edit my question and attasch the link there,
P.S ur gonna have to wright admin in the url after forward slash in home page

Comment: I am sure I found the issue in your code. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `products` array contains data similar to the `categories` array then I assume the product `id` properties are a number type. The `products.find` predicate function is using a strict equality (*`===`*) of a number-type `item.id` against the string-type `id` route path param (*Route path params are **always** a string type*). With strict equality check if the types are not the same then the operands are automatically not equal.

```js
console.log('5 === "5"', 5 === "5"); // false
```

You should instead use a "type-safe" comparison, e.g. string to string, or number to number.

```js
console.log('String(5) === "5"', String(5) === "5"); // true
console.log('5 === Number("5")', 5 === Number("5")); // true
```

I suggest converting the array element property to `String` since this covers strings ***and*** number-like strings.

```js
const productEdit = products.find((item) => String(item.id) === id);
```

There also appears to be a malformed edit link target in `ViewProducts`. The code has

```
to={`/admin/add_product/${id}`}
```

where the route path is `path="/add-product/:id"`.

The link target should be

```
to={`/admin/add-product/${id}`}
```

It is the difference between a hyphen in the path, and an underscore.

Comment: i tries ur solution 
 const productEdit = products.find((item) => String(item.id) === id);
but still it's routing to the path and not showing the layout

Comment: @Cable-Nerd Which path are you referring to, and what layout are you expecting to show? Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of the routes and UI (*you can mock all the DB data*) and provide exact reproduction steps to produce any issues you see, that we can inspect live?

Comment: @Cable-Nerd Any luck or update on a reproducible sandbox?

Comment: Thanks bro, looks like the only problem seems to be in a link typo and in not turning it into string, BTW dude why is clicking on product opn home page is not directing to the product-details page, like why is it not matvhing any routes

Comment: @Cable-Nerd I don't see any products on the "Home" page. Are you talking about clicking on the edit button of a product on the "View Products" page, or can you clarify that question?

Comment: no i'm talkin about products that are displayed on the main page whici is the home page where caraouseletc is shown, they're onClikcing the products it routes to a blank page with the id too but gives an error saying no route match @Drew Reese

Comment: @Cable-Nerd What is the route you refer to, or how would I navigate there via the UI in the sandbox?

Comment: by clicking on the image of the product any product @Drew Reese

Comment: @Cable-Nerd Ah, I see, the `"/"` route with the carousel... I just had to scroll down to find the images you referred to. From what I can tell the `App` component isn't rendering any `"/product-details/...."` route, so the error/warning makes sense to me. Are you rendering a route somewhere for product details? I only see a link to product details in the `ProductItem.jsx` file.

Comment: @Cable-Nerd This seems like an extracurricular issue to the topic of this post, it might be better to create a new SO post for this other specific issue. I think all you need is to add a route in `App` for the product details page you link to.

Comment: Thanks Again @Drew Reese may god bless u